# XPath to select nodes which don't only have one certain child node?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<div>
  <p>case a</p> # only has a text node, selected
  <p>case <a>b</a></p> # has a text node and an a node, selected
  <p><a>case c</a></p> # only has an a node, not selected
</div>
```

Is there a way to select `p` nodes which not only have `a` nodes, i.e. `<p>case a</p>` and `<p>case <a>b</a></p>`, but not `<p><a>case c</a></p>`.

Comment: Are you asking how to select the nodes which **don't** contain `<a>`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge not only contain `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//p[not(a) or node()[not(self::a)]]
```

will select all `p` elements that lack an `a` child **or** have child nodes that are not `a`s, which is equivalent to ***selecting `p` elements which have not only `a` children***,

```
<p>case a</p>
<p>case <a>b</a></p>
```

as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm crossing an edge case `<p><a>case d</a><br></p>`. Is it possible to remove this as well? Appreciate.

Comment: Yes, but first you'll have to characterize the properties of the new case that warrant its exclusion.  You  nicely characterized the original criteria for selection with a rule and examples.  What's the new criteria?  And you probably should create a new question for it.  Thanks.